# Are there official rules for crafting magic items?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, crafting

Is crafting magical items official in D&D 5e? I googled it, but 90% of everything I found is homebrew. If crafting is official, how do you do it, and what can you make? Is there some sort of list or something?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Are you asking as a DM or as a player?

Comment: From a player’s point of view

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### There are two versions of official rules for crafting

***Both require that you work with your DM.***  In either place that these rules appear, they are optional variants to the base rules.

#### Dungeon Master's Guide

The [first official optional rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/between-adventures#CraftingaMagicItem) released appear in the *Dungeon Master's Guide* in chapter 6 as part of the "Downtime Activities" section:

> **Crafting a Magic Item**
>
> Magic items are the DM’s purview, so you decide how they fall into the party’s possession. As an option, you can allow player characters to craft magic items.

An [alternative ruleset](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/xgte/downtime-revisited#CraftinganItem) is part of the optional variant to downtime as a whole (and one I personally think is more fleshed out) that appears in the supplement *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* in the "Downtime Revisited" section of chapter 2:

> ***Crafting Magic Items.*** Creating a magic item requires more than just time, effort, and materials. It is a long-term process that involves one or more adventures to track down rare materials and the lore needed to create the item.

#### What can you make?

With enough money, time, and resources the rules allow for the crafting of any magic item bar artifacts.  That being said, the *requirements necessitate DM input*.

With either of these rules, crafting magic items requires a formula:

> To start with, a character needs a formula for a magic item in order to create it. The formula is like a recipe. It lists the materials needed and steps required to make the item.

**There are no official rules for how these formula are created or attained.**
As such, whichever ruleset is being used, the limits of the crafting is dependent on which formula the DM allows the party to acquire.